# Columns not getting ordered in the row correctly bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have three columns and I need to arrange them like this in a row:

Interested listings | Basic profile | Connections

**And when the screen size is reduced to a phone size, it should be stacked like this:**

Basic profile
Interested listings
Connections

So I saw a few techniques which use push and pull and tried this:

```html
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Basic profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Interested listings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">Connections</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">Requests</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's appearing as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2BOB.png):
Basic profile | Interested listings | Connections

instead of:

Interested listings | Basic profile | Connections

I thought the col-lg-push and pull was supposed to swap the positions of the columns but I guess I'm missing something here and I'm not sure why the order remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex and flex order to change the column order on larger screens (I used md in the example, but you can use any size you want).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex">    
        <div class="order-md-2 col-md-4 col-lg-push-4">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Basic profile</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="order-md-1 col-md-4 col-lg-pull-4">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Interested listings</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="order-md-3 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">Connections</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">Requests</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think Bootstrap has a `col-lg-push-4` or a `col-lg-pull-4` style.